# Voice recognition : voice driven control

Tags: c#, c++, python, projects-and-solutions, voice-recognition

Few days ago I asked for a project idea for my B.tech Final year project.

Unfortunately couldn't got any cool idea.

Now I have got an idea which really pleases me and motivates me.

I want to ask to intelligent guys out there is following thing is feasible in 5 months:

The Project idea is :

**"A Voice Driven Controlling of The System"**

I want to make an application which will listen to voice of the user of system and run commands by voice instructions:

simplest examples would be like:

- open a media player, play list,  change the song,
- open any other application
- close some application
- close current window or application
- If possible make the application capable of learning new things on run time also. (planned for Second Phase if lack of time for completion of first phase)

Even if I'll be able to implement this much examples only it will be good enough for now, as the same project I have to continue next semester.

I want to know the feasibility of the project. Also please suggest me that what would be the best language to develop this app.

Also All the suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: More ideas for phase2: Instead of an application, you could do an embedded project on something like an ARM, running a linux machine, running your app :D. You could even sell it afterwards! About the learning part, I think you would have to use neural networks...it sounds complex.

Answer (score 0):

I think somebody beat you to it:

http://code.google.com/p/dragonfly/

note that you can use the Microsoft Windows speech recognition engine or Nuance's Dragon NaturallySpeaking.

Good luck